# How can I estimate the first derivative of an evaluated univariate function in C++?

Tags: c++, numerical-methods, derivative

I have a two vectors:

- Coordinates along an axis, `x`;
- An evaluation of a function on those coordinates, `f(x)`.

and I want to compute an estimate of the first derivative of `f` at these coordinates.

The function is a descriptor of a wavefunction and x is the dihedral angle.

Because the result vector must have the same length as the two existing vectors, I cannot use a manual implementation based on [Newton's difference quotient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Difference_quotient).

In Python, I can obtain such an estimate using the `scipy` library:

```
spline = UnivariateSpline(X, Y, k=4, s=0)
sd = spline.derivative(n=1)
```

Perhaps I can do something similar in C++?

Comment: Please don't describe your code, create a [mcve] of it to show us instead. And please take some time to read or refresh [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: There is nothing for this in the C++ standard library. Mathematically speaking, what is x and what is f(x)? Do you know what the derivative of f with respect to x is if x and f(x) are scalars? If x is a scalar and f(x) is a vector? If x is a vector and f(x) is a scalar? If both are vectors? Know what you want conceptually before throwing code at it.

Comment: Both f(x) and x are scalars and I don't know the exact form of f(x), but only its values.

Comment: @Rup: It's not a "best line fit" actually.

Comment: Perhaps you can. Good luck!

Comment: @TheOldJonny: Your Python code uses a degree-4 spline, which it creates based on the knots. You should search - using a search engine, and perhaps also on GitHub - for C/C++ libraries for working with such splines. The Eigen library has a [spline module](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/unsupported/classEigen_1_1Spline.html) which may fit the bill (not sure - haven't used it).

Comment: @einpoklum I don't know what you're replying to ;)

Comment: @einpoklum Oops, I guess I meant 'curve' or at least I wasn't thinking straight line specifically. Was just trying to understand where the derivatives were supposed to come from, but it's clear now from your comments - thanks

Comment: Thank you to all of you

Comment: If you want to write your own code, you may use the formulae for [numerical differentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_differentiation), since you have also the `x`vector, but you have to consider some "boundary conditions". The solution you wrote in python consists of creating a fit of the original function and then deriving the latter, you are not computing the derivatives of the original function (although you may achieve a good rate of approximation depending on `f`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd start with [pchip](https://github.com/boostorg/math/blob/develop/include/boost/math/interpolators/pchip.hpp).

Example:

```
#include <boost/math/interpolators/pchip.hpp>
// ...
using boost::math::interpolators::pchip;
auto f = pchip(std::move(x), std::move(y));
double t = 3.2;
std::cout << "f(" << t << " = " << f(t) << ", f'(" << t << ") = " << f.prime(t) << "\n";
```

If you don't like the "character" of pchip, then you have many [other options](https://github.com/boostorg/math/tree/develop/include/boost/math/interpolators).